# Fast read C structure when it contains char array

Tags: c#, performance, struct, c++-cli, unsafe

I have the following C structure

```
struct MyStruct {
    char chArray[96];
    __int64 offset;
    unsigned count;
}
```

I now have a bunch of files created in C with thousands of those structures. I need to read them using C# and speed is an issue.

I have done the following in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 108)]
public struct PreIndexStruct {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 96)]
    public string Key;
    public long Offset;
    public int Count;
}
```

And then I read the data from the file using

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(
       new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, 
                      FileShare.Read, bufferSize))) 
{
    long length = br.BaseStream.Length;
    long position = 0;

    byte[] buff = new byte[structSize];
    GCHandle buffHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buff, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    while (position < length) {
        br.Read(buff, 0, structSize);
        PreIndexStruct pis = (PreIndexStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
            buffHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(PreIndexStruct));
        structures.Add(pis);

        position += structSize;
    }
    buffHandle.Free();
}
```

This works perfectly and I can retrieve the data just fine from the files.

I've read that I can speedup things if instead of using GCHandle.Alloc/Marshal.PtrToStructure I use C++/CLI or C# unsafe code. I found some examples but they only refer to structures without fixed sized arrays.

My question is, for my particular case, is there a faster way of doing things with C++/CLI or C# unsafe code?

**EDIT**

Additional performance info (I've used ANTS Performance Profiler 7.4):

66% of my CPU time is used by calls to Marshal.PtrToStructure.

Regarding I/O, only 6 out of 105ms are used to read from the file.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't fast enough? Disk I/O is generally the actual bottleneck when reading files.

Comment: Just to confirm, your measurements are from Release version of your code, right?

Comment: (I've updated my answer earlier so that it works with your structs now - albeit with a modified version of the struct and with unsafe code. Take a look in case it's any use!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you don't explicitly need to use P/Invoke since you don't have to pass the struct back and forth between managed and native code. So you could do this instead. It would avoid this useless GC handle allocation, and allocate only what's needed.

```
public struct PreIndexStruct {
    public string Key;
    public long Offset;
    public int Count;
}

while (...) {
    ...
    PreIndexStruct pis = new PreIndexStruct();
    pis.Key = Encoding.Default.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(96));
    pis.Offset = reader.ReadInt64();
    pis.Count = reader.ReadInt32();
    structures.Add(pis);
}
```

I'm not sure you can be much faster than this.

Comment: Well, it allocates `byte[]` that's not really needed, but I'm not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: @svick- It's also possible to allocate a char[96] array, put in the 96 characters byte per byte, and use the `string(char[] value)` constructor. It may be faster, use less memory (this string ctor is internal call). I'm not sure... Otherwise, there is the unsafe possibility to avoid allocate any array.

Comment: Doing it this way reduced my execution time almost in half.

Comment: @morat - Great! did you use the sample code, or the more advanced suggestion in my comment?

Comment: I used the sample code for now. It's "reasonably" fast now; I need to finish the rest of my app before I optimize this part any further. If I need to make it even faster in the end, I'll come back to your suggestion in the comments and test to see if it improves my speed or not. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more correctly you want to use unmanaged code, this is what I would do:

1. Create a C++/CLI project and get your existing c# code ported and running there
2. Determine where your bottleneck is (use the profiler)
3. rewrite that section of the code in straight C++, call it from the C++/CLI code and make sure it works, profile it again
4. surround your new code with "#pragma unmanaged"
5. profile it again

You will probably get some level of speed increase, but it may not be what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for using the wrong terminology. I used ANTS profiler to look at my application. 66% of the CPU time is used by calls to Marshal.PtrToStructure. Regarding what you said, I have no idea how to do that in C++/CLI with my particular structure declared in C#.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with much fiddlyness to do a pretty quick read of some arrays of structs, but because this technique requires blittable types, the only way to do it is to make a fixed buffer of bytes for the Key instead of using a string.

If you do that, you have to use unsafe code so it's probably not really worth it.

However, just for the curious, this is how you can do a super-duper fast read and write of those structs, at the expense of having to allow unsafe code and a lot of fiddle:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 108)]
        public struct PreIndexStruct
        {
            public unsafe fixed byte Key[96];
            public long Offset;
            public int Count;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PreIndexStruct[] a = new PreIndexStruct[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
            {
                a[i].Count = i;

                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (byte* key = a[i].Key)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
                        {
                            key[j] = (byte)i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            using (var output = File.Create(@"C:\TEST\TEST.BIN"))
            {
                FastWrite(output, a, 0, a.Length);
            }

            using (var input = File.OpenRead(@"C:\TEST\TEST.BIN"))
            {
                var b = FastRead<PreIndexStruct>(input, a.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i)
                {
                    Console.Write("Count = " + b[i].Count + ", Key =");

                    unsafe
                    {
                        fixed (byte* key = b[i].Key)
                        {
                            // Here you would access the bytes in Key[], which would presumably be ANSI chars.

                            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
                            {
                                Console.Write(" " + key[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes a part of an array to a file stream as quickly as possible,
        /// without making any additional copies of the data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array elements.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="fs">The file stream to which to write.</param>
        /// <param name="array">The array containing the data to write.</param>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset of the start of the data in the array to write.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of array elements to write.</param>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown on error. See inner exception for <see cref="Win32Exception"/></exception>

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2001:AvoidCallingProblematicMethods", MessageId="System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle")]

        public static void FastWrite<T>(FileStream fs, T[] array, int offset, int count) where T: struct
        {
            int sizeOfT = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
            GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                uint bytesWritten;
                uint bytesToWrite = (uint)(count * sizeOfT);

                if
                (
                    !WriteFile
                    (
                        fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                        new IntPtr(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToInt64() + (offset*sizeOfT)),
                        bytesToWrite,
                        out bytesWritten,
                        IntPtr.Zero
                    )
                )
                {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to write file.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                Debug.Assert(bytesWritten == bytesToWrite);
            }

            finally
            {
                gcHandle.Free();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads array data from a file stream as quickly as possible,
        /// without making any additional copies of the data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the array elements.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="fs">The file stream from which to read.</param>
        /// <param name="count">The number of elements to read.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The array of elements that was read. This may be less than the number that was
        /// requested if the end of the file was reached. It may even be empty.
        /// NOTE: There may still be data left in the file, even if not all the requested
        /// elements were returned - this happens if the number of bytes remaining in the
        /// file is less than the size of the array elements.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="IOException">Thrown on error. See inner exception for <see cref="Win32Exception"/></exception>

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2001:AvoidCallingProblematicMethods", MessageId="System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle")]

        public static T[] FastRead<T>(FileStream fs, int count) where T: struct
        {
            int sizeOfT = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));

            long bytesRemaining  = fs.Length - fs.Position;
            long wantedBytes     = count * sizeOfT;
            long bytesAvailable  = Math.Min(bytesRemaining, wantedBytes);
            long availableValues = bytesAvailable / sizeOfT;
            long bytesToRead     = (availableValues * sizeOfT);

            if ((bytesRemaining < wantedBytes) && ((bytesRemaining - bytesToRead) > 0))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Requested data exceeds available data and partial data remains in the file.", "Dmr.Common.IO.Arrays.FastRead(fs,count)");
            }

            T[] result = new T[availableValues];

            GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result, GCHandleType.Pinned);

            try
            {
                uint bytesRead = 0;

                if
                (
                    !ReadFile
                    (
                        fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                        gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                        (uint)bytesToRead,
                        out bytesRead,
                        IntPtr.Zero
                    )
                )
                {
                    throw new IOException("Unable to read file.", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
                }

                Debug.Assert(bytesRead == bytesToRead);
            }

            finally
            {
                gcHandle.Free();
            }

            return result;
        }


        /// <summary>See the Windows API documentation for details.</summary>

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1415:DeclarePInvokesCorrectly")]
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

        private static extern bool ReadFile
        (
            IntPtr hFile,
            IntPtr lpBuffer,
            uint nNumberOfBytesToRead,
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );

        /// <summary>See the Windows API documentation for details.</summary>

        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Interoperability", "CA1415:DeclarePInvokesCorrectly")]
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

        private static extern bool WriteFile
        (
            IntPtr hFile,
            IntPtr lpBuffer,
            uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
            out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
            IntPtr lpOverlapped
        );
    }
}
```